# GCD and LCM of unknown integers

Tags: number-theory

I need to find all $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $gcd(a,b)=18$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=720$.

Any ideas how to start?

Comment: I think you can use that $gcd(a,b)×lcm(a,b)=a×b$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Lets say the required pair of numbers are $a,b$
Since the $\gcd(a,b) = 18$  , we have :
$a = 18a'$
$b = 18b'$
$\gcd(a',b')=1$
$$\text{lcm}(a,b)\times \gcd(a,b) = ab \implies   18\times 720 = 18a'18b'\implies a'b' =40$$

That means you just need to find all the coprime pairs $a',b'$ whose product is $40$

Comment: I think you mean "all the coprime pairs $a',b'$."

Comment: Oops yes, let me fix it ty :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some suggestions for thoughts on this problem:

If $\text{GCD}(a,b) = 18$, then $18$ must divide both $a$ and $b$, so you can consider only multiples $a=18n$ and $b=18m$.

Since $\text{LCM}(a,b)=720$, you know that both $a$ and $b$ divides $720$. You can factor out the $18$ to see that $720/18 = 40$, which tells you something about $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

From the factorizations $720=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5^1$ and $18=2^1\cdot3^2\cdot5^0.$ we see that $a=2^{x_1}\cdot3^{x_2}\cdot5^{x_3}$ and $b=2^{y_1}\cdot3^{y_2}\cdot5^{y_3}$, where $\max(x_1,y_1)=4,$ $\min(x_1,y_1)=1,$ $\max(x_2,y_2)=\min(x_2,y_2)=2,$ $\max(x_3,y_3)=1,$ $\min(x_3,y_3)=0;$ that is, $\{x_1,y_1\}=\{1,4\},$ $x_2=y_2=2,$ $\{x_3,y_3\}=\{0,1\}.$ There are four solutions. For example, one of them is $a=2^1\cdot3^2\cdot5^1=90,b=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5^0=144.$

Comment: Aren't there only two solutions since they can't have any further common factors? The only other solution is 18 and 720. I.e. divide your 4 by 2!.

Comment: @jdods The problem has two unknowns $a$ and $b$. The four solutions are $(18,720),(90,144),(144,90),(720,18).$

Comment: I figured it made more sense to not distinguish between (a,b) and(b,a).